# Communication between components with Vue and routes

Tags: vue.js, routes, components

I'm just starting with vue but I'm stuck here: I want to pass info from a component to another one. I'm using routes.

If you click on teacher > student list > check (the first one) you render a component (student grade). There, I want to output data from the array students which is stored in student list.

How can I do that?

This is my work:
https://codesandbox.io/s/61xk8xjy63

Comment: Hi. 
Use params in `vue-router` for data transfer. Link: https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/passing-props.html

Comment: I tryed but I'm doing something wrong. Could you please fork my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend use `params` in `vue-router`.

Sample: https://codesandbox.io/s/zrk6r0o4ml.

In sample used named path (docs: https://router.vuejs.org/essentials/named-routes.html) and params path (docs: https://router.vuejs.org/essentials/passing-props.html).

Also, i use `v-for` for display array of data (file `StudentList.vue`, docs: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Mapping-an-Array-to-Elements-with-v-for).

Good luck.